# MVC3 TextArea issue with HTML rendering

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, render, encode

I have a C# MVC3 .Net Web App.  I have several TextArea controls.  They contain HTML strings populated from our DB.  Some of the TextArea controls are CkEditor and they work fine.  They have a property called 'htmlEncodeOutput'.  This avoids ASP.NET security issues.  The standard TextAreas are barfing when I navigate to a new page.  I believe it is due to the embedded HTML.  Is there a property for TextAreas that I can set to encode the embedded HTML?

Here's the error that is being thrown:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (item.SowDescription="...; it sodas<br />
<strong><em>...").
```

Comment: Need more explanation to understand what's the exact issue?

Comment: It might help if you include the actual exception you're getting.

Comment: It would help.  It's throwing an exception "Not in a UnitoFWork".  But that's not the issue.  I think that's getting thrown as a side effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  In the text area I use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode for the property being rendered.  Example below:

```
<textarea rows="3" cols="33" class="readonly"
            readonly="readonly" 
            id = "@Id">
    @HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Description)
</textarea>
```